# Proof about the kernel of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove that if $\ker A \neq \{ 0\}$ where $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$, then $\ker (AB) \neq\{ 0\}$ for all Matrices $B \in \mathbb{K}^{m\times k}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use definition. It is trivial.

Comment: $Null(A)=\{v:Av=0\}$ and $Null(AB)=\{w: ABw=0\}$. Apparently, $Av=0$ does not imply that $Null(AB)\ne \{0\}$. For example, $A=(1, -1)$, $(-1, 1) (1, 1)^t =0$ implies $Null(A)\ne\{0\}$. However, if $B=(1,-1)^t $, then $Null(AB)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ker(A)$ is nontrivial, then $Ax=0$ for some nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Consider a simple case. For example, if $n=m=2$, then

$$Ax=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 a_{11} + x_2a_{12}\\
x_1a_{21} + x_2a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Since we're considering the case when $Ax=0$, we have

\begin{align*}
x_1 a_{11} + x_2a_{12} &= 0,\\
x_1a_{21} + x_2a_{22} &=0. 
\end{align*}

So we can choose

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

and $x=(1,-1)^T$ to satisfy these equations. With this choice of $A$, we see that $\ker(A)$ is nontrivial. Now we want to try to find a matrix

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

such that $ABy=0$ has only the trivial solution $y=(0,0)^T$ (i.e. $\ker(AB) = 0$), for our choice of $A$ above. Can you find such a matrix $B$?

Comment: Based on the original question, $B$ does not have to have the same dimensions as $A$.  What if for example $B$ is a 2x1 matrix?